# Is it correct to say "10 apples plus 2 apples equal 12 apples" or "10 apples plus 2 apples equals 12 apples"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

It seems that most examples in dictionaries use the verb "equal" as a singular verb even its subjects are plural

For example, *[Three and three equals six.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/equal_2?q=equals)*

So, can "**equal**" never be used as a plural verb?

Is it correct to say "**10 apples plus 2 apples equal 12 apples**" or "**10 apples plus 2 apples equals 12 apples**"?

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the word 'equal' is the mathematical expression to its left. Thus it takes the singular verb.

If you imply multiple expressions: "All numbers divided by zero equal infinity ", it takes the plural verb.